# services (threads) in sequence java

Tags: java, multithreading, service

i have a task to make 3 (A,B,C) services depending on each other. When service A starts, service B can start, when service B starts , service C can start and when C stops, B can stop, and when B stops A can stop. 
I have manage to start threads and make a switch from one to another with status option. I have to say that i dont know so much things about java but i have just started to learn java so i'm new in this so any help,suggestion and etc would be great.

Also I have 3 almost the same classes so can anyone tell em how can I replace those 3 classes with one? Is there any way?

Here is my code:

```
public class service_class {
    int status=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        service_class service_class = new service_class();

        A1 a=new A1(service_class);
        B1 b=new B1(service_class);
        C1 c=new C1(service_class);

        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();

    }
}

class A1 extends Thread{
    service_class service_class;

    A1(service_class service_class){
        this.service_class = service_class;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            synchronized (service_class) {
                 while(service_class.status!=1){
                        service_class.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.print("A started" + "\n");
                    service_class.status = 2;
                    service_class.notifyAll();

                    while(service_class.status!=7){
                        service_class.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.print("A stoped" + "\n");
                    service_class.status = 1;
                    service_class.notifyAll();
                }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 1 :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

class B1 extends Thread{

    service_class service_class;

    B1(service_class service_class){
        this.service_class = service_class;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            synchronized (service_class) {

                    while(service_class.status!=2){
                        service_class.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.print("B started " + "\n");
                    service_class.status = 4;
                    service_class.notifyAll();

                    while(service_class.status!=6){
                        service_class.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.print("B stoped" + "\n");
                    service_class.status = 7;
                    service_class.notifyAll();
                }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 2 :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}


class C1 extends Thread{

    service_class service_class;

    C1(service_class service_class){
        this.service_class = service_class;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            synchronized (service_class) {
                 while(service_class.status!=4){
                        service_class.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.print("C started" + "\n");
                    service_class.status = 5;
                    service_class.notifyAll();

                    while(service_class.status!=5){
                        service_class.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.print("C stoped" + "\n");
                    service_class.status = 6;
                    service_class.notifyAll();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 4 :"+e.getMessage());
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the services strictly ordered?  Or could you have `B1` and `B2` that both start after `A` but it doesn't matter which `B` starts first?

Comment: They are strictly ordered. Do you think that i'm on the good way?

Answer (score 3):

> I have 3 almost the same classes so can anyone tell em how can I replace those 3 classes with one? Is there any way?

It looks like the differences between the 3 classes `A`, `B` and `C` are:

- the name string that gets printed, and
- the state values that each one tests and sets.

So just replace these with `final` instance variables, and initialize them with values passed to the (unified) classes constructor.

---

However ...

Extending `Thread` is generally thought to be a bad idea.  For a start, it makes it difficult to use thread pooling.  A better approach is to use the standard `Thread` class, and pass it a `Runnable` instance when you construct it.  In fact, if you are using thread pooling or and Executor service or whatever, you won't even need to create and manage the threads yourself.

As for the wait / notify stuff, it is easier to use a higher level synchronization construct (such as `CountDownLatch`).

Comment: Tnx for helping me, but do you have maybe some basic example how to do it? For me is very hard to understand it on example it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

A `CountDownLatch` is initialized with a given count. The `await` method block until the count reaches zero due to invocations of the `countDown()` method (by other threads), after which all waiting threads are released. My suggestion is writing a superclass that:

- provides a latch with a initial count of 1
- accepts another instance of that class or a `CountDownLatch` that is to be waited before execution
- decrements its latch on start
- wraps that logic in `run` and provides an abstract method `innerRun` where the actual code will be implemented.

  ```
  abstract class LatchedRunnable extends Runnable {

  private CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);
  private CountDownLatch wait;
  public Foo(LatchedRunnable waitFor) {
    this.wait=waitFor.latch;
  }
  public Foo(CountDownLatch waitFor) {
    this.wait=waitFor;
  }

  final run () {
   //wait for the other thread
   if (wait!=null) 
      try {wait.await();} 
      catch (InterruptedException e) {return;}

   //signal that we have started
   latch.countDown();

   //actually start
   innerRun();
  }

  protected abstract void innerRun(); //do stuff here
  }



  class Foo extends LatchedRunnable {
     Foo(LatchedRunnable waitFor) {super(waitFor);}
     protected void innerRun() {...}
  }

  class Bar extends LatchedRunnable { 
     Bar(LatchedRunnable waitFor) {super(waitFor);}
     protected void innerRun() {...}
  }

  Foo foo = new Foo(null);
  Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
  ```

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @StephenC I think it does now

Comment: Agreed ... though you don't actually explain the code.  It would be better if you gave him an explanation, and left him to write the code for himself.

Comment: Tnx so much for helping me. I agree with Stephen C can you explain it a little bit more because my knowledge of java is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

CountDownLatch, in my understanding, is a mechanism to achieve synchronization without entering a deadlock. So here it goes,

Consider, Thread1 performs a task such a file read. Once complete file has been read, another thread could process the file contents and grab certain information. And now a third thread is responsible to copy the information to a DB.

Assume there are multiple clients using the same steps above and in the same order:

1. FileRead
2. FileProcessor
3. DBUpdate

Instead of handling everything sequentially, we create three thread pools.

```
ThreadPool<FileReaderThread> poolA;
ThreadPool<FileProcessorThread> poolB;
ThreadPool<DBUpdate> poolC;
```

As a new request comes in, a countdownlatch will be created with an appropriate count. As a thread from poolA completes its work, the count will be decremented. Once this count reaches 0, thread from poolB will be invoked.Similarly another countdownlatch will used to synchronize thread from poolB and poolC. Ideally, we achieve a sequential process with CountDownLatch.

Please correct if something is incorrect.